# Replace every instance of a color on a website just by using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, colors

I am building a WordPress website with a web building plugin. However, this plugin allows custom CSS code to be added to my website. I just need to replace every color `#d4d4d4` with `#ffffff`. Is this possible using *only* CSS code?

I tried to use jQuery code I found, but that is probably not the solution.

Comment: No this is not possible with CSS

Answer (score -1):

It is possible: identify all the selectors that use `#d4d4d4`, and add that selector to your selector.

If this is the current CSS:

```css
.h1 {
    color: #d4d4d4;
}

.alpha .bravo #charlie {
    color: #d4d4d4;
}
```

Then you can add this:

```css
.h1,
.alpha .bravo #charlie {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

The CSS may also use variables, in which case changing (at least a few occurrences of) that color to white may be very easy.

Comment: What I loathe most about downvotes is when no explanation is given. I think this answer makes sense if you have to overwrite included CSS and can't just go in and change it. I don't have any experience with WordPress.